# boolean algebra question here very short?

Tags: boolean-algebra

We have the Boolean expression Y=A'BC' + ABC'+A'BC

Simplify it.
Now, this is what I did

```
Y=BC'(A'+A) +A'BC.
```

Now using idempotence

```
Y=BC' + A'BC=B(C'+A'C)
```

I just dont know how to continue this.
The result in my book is `Y=A'B+BC'`

Comment: `A'BC'+ABC'+A'BC=A'BC'+ABC'+A'BC+A'BC'=(A'+A)BC'+A'B(C+C')=BC'+A'B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Y=A'BC+ABC'+A'BC
Now, we know that A+A=A,
so,
Y=A'BC'+A'BC'+ABC'+A'BC
Y=A'BC'+A'BC+A'BC'+ABC'
Y=A'B(C'+C)+BC'(A+A')
we know that A+A'=1
so,
Y=A'B+BC'